# External hyperlinks to control Openlayers map

Tags: openlayers

I have a basic map defined like show below (pseudo code).

After the map.addLayers call there is a displayData(theid) which I want to call from the main body of the html document, the problem is I can't call the method.  I can achieve what I am after if I bind an onclick event to the id of the <a> tag but there's going to be too many links to bind to each and every <a> tag

Clicking on one of the hyperlinks below results in no method displayData() defined.

Thanks for reading!

```
  <script>
        Ext.onReady(function() {
        map = new OpenLayers.Map();
        basemap = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(...);
        mylines = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(...);
        selected_items = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(...);
        map.addLayers([basemap, mylines, selected_items]);

        //attach an onclick even for the button on the search results page
        function displayData(theid) {
            OpenLayers.Request.GET({
                url: 'http://1.1.1.1:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&featureId='+theid,
                proxy: "../gis/geoserver.seam?url=",
                success: function(response) {
                //if were successful then add the returned features to the map and zoom to the extent
                var gmlReader = new OpenLayers.Format.GML({ extractAttributes: true });
                selected_items.removeAllFeatures();
                selected_items.addFeatures(gmlReader.read(response.responseText));
                map.zoomToExtent(selected_items.getDataExtent());
            }
        });
    }
}
</script>

<body>
    <div id="map" class="smallmap"></div>
    <br/><a href="" onlick="displayData('feature1');">View on map</a>
    <br/><a href="" onlick="displayData('feature2');">View on map</a>
    <br/><a href="" onlick="displayData('feature3');">View on map</a>
    <br/><a href="" onlick="displayData('feature4');">View on map</a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript has function scope which means that `displayData` is not 'visible' from outside

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
... stuff here is executed but is not visible from outside
}
```

To solve this you can declare a fake empty displayData outside of it or bind the click event of the links (via a class).

Comment: Thanks for that, I understand it's a scoping issue.  I like the sound of attaching it to the window object, any ideas how I would do this?  Thanks again.

Comment: I think the window object idea is broken (comes too late), can you attach a click event using Sencha Ext ? Add the same class to each link at tell Sencha Ext to call your displayData function on click. Do all of that after your function has been declared, so inside the onReady.

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me in the right direction, I had already bound an event to a div (via id) but didnt realise I could do the same with a class, <div class="maplink" featureid="myid">link</div> then Ext.select('.maplink').on('click', function(e, t) { zoomToFeature(t.getAttribute('featureid')); }); - job done, thanks again!

Comment: You may also upvote my answer to give me some extra points :)

Comment: Sorry, tried that but I don't have enough "reputation points" :(

Comment: Most excellent, just pushed me above the threshold!  Thanks again.